# AllowDiskTrue parameter in aggregate query not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb 2.4 and I am stuck at some issue with aggregate query.
I am query on a large data set and I get this error:

```
Thu Nov 12 10:11:10.701 aggregate failed: {
"errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
"code" : 16389,
"ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898
```

I am using `{"allowDiskTrue" : 1}`, but I guess it is not working. Can you please help.

My collection has N Fields and I want to find unique values in Field2. The date size is almost around 50 to 60 GB.

I am using this pipeline:

```
[{'$match':{'date_time':{'$gte':from_date,'$lt':start_date}}},{'$group':   {'_id':{"FIELD2":"$FIELD2",},"count":{'$sum':1}}}]
```

Comment: The answer is of course that `allowDiskUse` was not introduced until MongoDB 2.6. So you cannot use it without upgrading. It also will not solve that problem as the BSON limit still exists. Instead your aggregate query needs to change what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks Blakes.. So can you please suggest something to solve this since upgrading to 2.6 will not be possible in near future.

Comment: My "suggestion" was to instead show what you are doing in your aggregation pipeline and the result you want to achieve. The error occurs because the BSON limit is being exceeded, so the likely cause is pushing items to an array. We need that information to suggest something to solve this. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33669197/edit) your question to include the information.